# Equality of fractions of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $K$ be a field and $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be indeterminates.  Suppose $h(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in K(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ hence $h= f/g$ with $f,g \in K[X_1, \ldots, X_n]$. Now, apparently, if $h$ is not a constant, $h(X_1^m, \ldots, X_n^m)$ covers an infinite subset of $K(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ if $m$ runs through the non-negative integers (maybe even different values for each $m$?). This seems far from trivial to me. What would be a neat way of proving this?

Comment: I'd try first the case $n=1$.

Comment: I did, but don't see how it works.  $f(X)/g(X)=f(X^k)/g(X^k)$ iff $f(X)g(X^k)=f(X^k)g(X)$. I really don't see why this would be impossible.

Comment: (if $f$ and $g$ have the same degree, I mean)